# c++ calling int twice

Tags: c++, integer

I was writing a code, and accidentally put `int` before a variable twice, and noticed something different in the end product.

```
int main ()
{
    int number = 123456789;
    int step = 0;

    while (number>0)
    {
        cout << number%10 << endl;
        number = number/10;
        step = step+1;
        cout << "step ; " << step << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
9
step ; 1
8
step ; 2
7
step ; 3
6 ...
```

However, when I called it this way:

```
int main ()
{
    int number = 123456789;
    int step = 0;

    while (number>0)
    {
        cout << number%10 << endl;
        number = number/10;
        int step = step+1;
        cout << "step ; " << step << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output suddenly changed to:

```
9
step ; 11006125
8
step ; 11006126
7
step ; 11006127
6
```

Can someone please explain the difference, so that I will be mindful next time?

Comment: [Turn up your warning levels](https://godbolt.org/z/xq75d9nhW) and treat them as errors (because that's exactly what they are). The will not only tell you when you're probably doing something illogical, they'll hint at why as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Although surprisingly, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`, it's not catching the real problem, just noticing you never use the outer `step`. If you delete the `int step = 0;` outside the `while` loop, or use it in some way so it's not unused, it compiles without complaint, despite `int step = step + 1;` being errant nonsense. That's... not great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is block scoped. When you redeclare `step` inside the `while` loop (by using `int step` instead of just `step`), you "shadow" the `step` from outside that scope; while the outer `step` (with value `0`) still *exists*, it *cannot* be read directly from the inner scope (a pointer/reference to the outer `step` with a different name could read/write the data, you just can't read the outer `step` directly through that name).

The outer `step` is invisible, so `int step = step + 1;` translates as "please assign to the local `step` the value of whatever is already stored in the local `step` (which, not existing until that moment, has no defined value yet) after adding `1`". Since the `step` it reads from is garbage, this is undefined behavior, and in practice, it gets garbage (whatever junk happened to be left on the stack in that position from before you entered the `while`).

The second and subsequent creations of the inner `step` are still undefined behavior, but in this case (and in most cases where loop unrolling isn't involved) the compiler chose to reuse the same storage for them as the prior use of inner `step` (that expired when that iteration of the loop ended). Thus, as a coincidence of the new inner `step` reading from the same memory location as the expired inner `step`, it increments normally from then on, based on the original garbage value as a base.

But again, to be clear, **all of this is undefined behavior**. Be thankful you didn't get nasal demons, and only use the first form in the future. I'll note, if you enable all warnings, any compiler worth its salt should detect this error (the entire error exists in the scope of a single line); sadly, it appears at least GCC is not worth its salt, because [the only thing it detects, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` is that you didn't use the *outer* `step` variable](https://godbolt.org/z/xq75d9nhW). If you used it, or deleted the declaration of the outer `step`, [it compiles with no warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/vKaW7cPWh), so I guess you're stuck just remembering not to initialize a variable in terms of its own value.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you declare a second variable, which is also called `step`, but is visible only inside the loop.